# how to change the visual force page to look like the standard detail page section

Tags: visualforce, community, visualforce-component, css

I have created a visual force page and embedded in the accounts. But visualforce page looks different in the section when embedded (that is the background-color is gray and does not like the standard section.

So is there a way to display VF page in detail page as standard section is displayed in detail page.

Regards,

khan

Comment: a couple of screen shots might make your question clearer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using pageblocks and your embedded Visualforce looks like this:

[image]

so like the old UI, thick bars and grey background, you can set the mode attribute of the pageblock to mainDetail:

```
<apex:pageBlock mode="mainDetail">
```

and this will then match the standard theme.  Note that it will still have a slight indent compared to the main page, this is because of the way that VF pages are iframed into regular pages.

[image]

Comment: Hi Bob,It helped me a lot.This was what i was looking for. Thanks for the quick answer. Regards,khan